# How to implement error boundary in react with server side rendering in nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

ComponentDidCatch (which is used in implementing error boundaries) does not seem to work on server side.
This is a current limitation in react, has anyone found any work-around to this problem?

Answer (score -2):

```
import React from "react";

class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError() {
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      return "Internal Error.";
    }

    return this.props.children;
  }
}
```

Comment: Catching an error from SSR is not supported as document says. https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html